# Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. What am i doing wrong as i just want to add 10 to the z variable

```
print ("Hello World")

x=int(input("Enter X"))
y=int(input("Enter Y"))
z=int(input("Enter Z")) + 10

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)

print (max(x,y,z))

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: What inputs are you providing?

Comment: There is likely other code you're not showing us, as this code works properly.

Comment: You probably have something like `max = 10` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Which line is getting the error? Show the full traceback.

Comment: Im so sorry this code does work when i tried it in IDLE python. I seem to be getting the error when using it in Jupyter workbook

Comment: I solved it. I was using the code after some other code in a previous cell on my workbook. Problem solved when i start a new one. Rookie error, sorry guys.

Comment: I had this as well using Jupyter, just restarted kernel and then it worked ok

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 should read:

```
z = (int(input("Enter Z"))+10)
```